# Stack overflow when hot reloading a reducer with React Native and Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, hot-module-replacement

I'm using `Redux` with React Native and `HMR`. When I change a reducer, the accept bubbles up to my `configureStore.js` file which calls this:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(() => {
        const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index').default;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
}
```

But then HMR keeps on searching the references in a loop until the stack overflow.
Could it be that there's a circular reference somewhere? If so, any tips for tracking it down? I've tried stepping through the `require.js` code but the 'references' are kept just as numbers making it hard to track down the right file.

Comment: I have a similar issue. the initial `store` object for me becomes undefined, which--though not idiomatic--is a problem when you use `store` directly. At first, that was the only problem, but over time, now it just breaks down all together (red screen of death) when I update the reducer. I'm assuming tht comes from having adding packages such as `redux-storage` or some other middleware. Updating actions are even more of a problem--those never worked well. My assumption is I need to do more in the function passed to `module.hot.accept`. I.e. redo everything I initially did in `configureStore` .

Comment: UPDATE: your question got me thinking about this again, and I finally solved it lol. Not sure if it applies to you, but what I did is 2 things: I did exactly what I hypothesized where I wasn't re-configuring the store properly with redux storage, so I did that. I.e. I made sure all the prior steps to setup the reducer were done again in `module.hot.accept`. Then as far as the actions go, I stopped importing them into my `configureStore` file, as I wasn't using them--that solved the issue where changing my action files broke the store, which couldn't properly "accept" the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my exact code if you want to examine it:

```
export default function configureStore() {
  engine = createEngine('appstate');
  engine = filter(engine, null, ['appStateLoaded', 'appReady', 'tourReady', 'tourPage', 'tooltipStep', 'connected']);
  const cacheState = storage.createMiddleware(engine); //OLD PARAMETER:  , [LOAD, 'SET_TOUR_READY', 'SET_TOUR_PAGE']  ... replaced by reducer key filtering above instead

  enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk, cacheState),
    devTools({
      name: Platform.OS,
      hostname: '10.0.1.201',
      port: 5678,
      filters: {blacklist: ['REDUX_STORAGE_SAVE']}
    })
  );

  //reset reducer state on LOGOUT
  const appReducer = combineReducers(reducers);
  const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
      state = undefined;
    }

    return appReducer(state, action);
  }

  reducer = storage.reducer(rootReducer);


  store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);

  //retreive previously cached state and inject into Redux store!
  const load = storage.createLoader(engine);
  load(store)
      .then((newState) => console.log('Loaded state:', newState))
      .catch(() => console.log('Failed to load previous state'));


  if(module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(() => {
      let nextRootReducer = storage.reducer(rootReducer);
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);

      load(store)
          .then((newState) => console.log('Loaded state:', newState))
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

It should give you a solid example of how to use various middleware with `module.hot.accept`. ...As far as the "circular reference" thing goes--the only thing to do is check your reducers and make sure they don't import each other. I think I've seen this exact issue in fact--ES6 modules can properly address cycles initial building, but perhaps the HMR build process cannot. And that's all. So you end up thinking you have code that works, but it basically doesn't support HMR. I'd setup a quick test app and implement their `hot.module.accept` code and verify it works for you. Maybe you'll have to adjust one thing--but since you have so little code, it will be easy to find--and then make that same fix in your own code. If that doesn't surface the issue, then minimize what you're doing with redux in your app temporarily until you isolate what was causing the problem. ..Wish I had more suggestions for ya.